# Почему в консольном приложении, когда делаю скриншоты html, происходит рост занимаемой памяти?

Tags: c#, утечка-памяти, консоль

Почему в консольном приложении, когда в цикле делаю скриншоты `html` страниц - происходит рост количества памяти, занимаемого приложением?
Чем более оно работает, тем более растёт объём.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleAppScreenShot
{
class Program
{
    static String pathApp = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath.ToString();
    static string url = "http://www.ya.ru";
    static int width = 960, height = 1380;
    static bool isDownloadScreenComplete = false;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hi");

        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                isDownloadScreenComplete = false;
                RunGenerateScreenshotThread(url, i);

                int number = 0;
                while (!isDownloadScreenComplete) // 5-ти минутный цикл ожидания скрина
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                    if (number > 3000)
                        throw new Exception(string.Format(" Ошибка цикла ожидания потока закачки снимка экрана. Ожидание составляет: {0} минут.", (number / 600).ToString()));

                    number++;
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ошибка: {0}", ex.Message);
        }
    }

    static void RunGenerateScreenshotThread(string url, int count)
    {
            var th = new Thread(() =>
            {
                WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
                // Set the size of the WebBrowser control
                wb.Width = width;
                wb.Height = height;

                //wb.DocumentCompleted += GenerateScreenshotCompleted;
                wb.Navigate(url);
                while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) { System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents(); }
                try
                {
                    // Get a Bitmap representation of the webpage as it's rendered in the WebBrowser control
                    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(wb.Width, wb.Height);
                    wb.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, wb.Width, wb.Height));
                    wb.Dispose();

                    // Save Thumbnail to a File
                    bitmap.Save(string.Format("d:\\1\\Screenshot{0}.png", count), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                    bitmap.Dispose();

                    count++;
                    Console.WriteLine("Natigated to OK {0}", count);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Ошибка: {0}", ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    isDownloadScreenComplete = true;
                    Application.ExitThread();   // Stops the thread
                }
            });
            th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            th.Start();
    }
}
}
```

Спасибо.

Comment: Посмотрите код приведённый [тут][1].


  [1]: http://www.msdr.ru/4/

Answer (score 1):

> Навскидку - не вызываете Dispose() для вашего WebBrowser. Вообще, лучше для таких целей использовать using.

- А чем отличается использование using, от явного вызова Dispose()? Если на то пошло, какая разница, кроме как блок using выльется в явный вызов Dispose() в CIL коде, после компиляции.

Comment: `using` эквивалентен `try (what) finally (dispose)` -- собственно, именно этим он и отличается от явного вызова `Dispose`. Вот у автора, например, из-за этого `Dispose` для `bitmap` никогда не будет вызван, если в `bitmap.Save` произойдет исключение.

Comment: Спасибо,  учёл использование using, но ненашёл где вставить поправленный код, создал новый топик здесь:
http://hashcode.ru/questions/189796/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-webbrowser-%D0%B2-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8

Comment: @EgorychMaster

- На самом деле, как я сейчас посмотрел, дело не в использовании `using` и не в `Dispose,` а в чем-то более фундаментальным. То есть, переписывание вашу штуку через `Parallel.ForEach` с собственным `TaskScheduler'`ом (для работы в `Single-Threaded Apartment`) правильно решает задачу -- убирает проблемы с выделением памяти и действительно работает мультипоточно.

- Почему в случае вашего кода память не очищается, для меня, например, пока что остается загадкой. Попробую для вашего нового вопроса поизучать внимательнее, этот же вопрос я пока что закрою.

Comment: Благодарю.