# Почему поток с компонентом WebBrowser в цикле приводит к неработоспособности и росту памяти

Tags: c#, webbrowser

Поток с WebBrowser после определённой итерации зависает в ожидании примерно на 5 минут в коде потока:

```
while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) 
  { System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents(); }
```

где значение состояния равно:

```
wb.ReadyState == Uninitialized или Interactive
```

в итоге возвращает страницу "Navigation canceled" - либо  возвращает её уже с 5 минутными задержками.

1. Почему компонент WebBrowser использует IE как 7-ой версии, если у меня в системе стоит IE8?
2. Почему компонент WebBrowser перестаёт отдавать страницы?
3. Почему объём память растёт приложения и в итоге занимает около 800 мб?

У меня стоит задача сохранить отображение страницы на жёсткий диск, используя консольное приложение. Возможно можно как-то в pdf или ещё в какой формат сохранить, чтобы можно было увидеть содержимое HTML странцы.

Я задавал вопрос [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/188765/c-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%8E-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-html-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8?answer_sort=newest) но ненашёл где написать продолжение:)

Буду рад любому ценному комментарию.

```
    class Program
    {
    static string url = "http://www.whatbrowser.org";
    static int width = 960, height = 1380;
    static int count = 0;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hi");

        try
        {
            int number = 1000;
            for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
            {
                var th = new Thread(obj => RunGenerateScreenshotThread((string)obj));
                th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                th.Start(url);
                th.Join();

                count++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("All successfully completed!");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    static void RunGenerateScreenshotThread(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            using (WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser())
            {
                // Set the size of the WebBrowser control
                wb.Width = width;
                wb.Height = height;

                //wb.DocumentCompleted += GenerateScreenshotCompleted;
                wb.Navigate(url);

                while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) 
                  { System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents(); }

                if (wb.DocumentTitle == "Navigation Canceled")
                    Console.WriteLine("Natigated ERROR {0}", count);
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Natigated OK {0}", count);
                }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            Application.ExitThread();   // Stops the thread
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

1. нужно [явно включить](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/more-ie8-extensibility-improvements) использования для своего приложения, прописав в реестре ключик.
2. что третий вопрос является ответом на второй.
3. а вот это сложный вопрос. сейчас практически все браузеры кушают очень много.

**upd**

Как бы я сделал. Отдельное приложение, которое получает два параметра - урл и куда сохранить (можно через параметры, можно через пайп). Его задача проста - загрузил, заскриншотил и отдал.

Второе приложение в цикле запускает первое, передавая ему параметры (на первых порах это может быть обычный батник).

плюсы:

- очень легко получается сделать для разных версий IE - просто два приложения, для одного прописан правильный webbrowser
- падения "скриншотерра" безопасно для основного приложения.
- так как приложение закрывается каждый раз, то это такой "костыль" против утечек.

минусы:

- возможно некое падение скорости (но это ещё нужно проверить)
- нужно следить за дочерними процессами

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь :) Сделал отдельное приложение - работает :)

Один из минусов подтвердился - при запуске приложения довольно интенсивно используеться процессор :)

Comment: А вот теперь можно улучшить. Сделайте  работу через сокет/пайп и пусть это дополнительное приложение сможет конвертировать несколько страниц. Основная программа запускает, дает подключиться к себе и начинает процесс. А далее, раз на 10 конвертаций просто перезапускает дочерний процесс. Либо контроллирует используемую память и перезапускает по  необходимости.

Comment: Спасибо за идею :)

Answer (score 1):

Браузер можно запускать в отдельном Thread + Task.
Работает в WinForms и Console Application

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

static Task<T> Navigate<T>(Uri url, Func<HtmlDocument,T> callback) {
   var ts = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
   var t = new Thread(() => {
     var wb = new WebBrowser() { AllowNavigation=true, ScriptErrorsSuppressed=true };
     wb.DocumentCompleted += (s, e) => ts.SetResult(callback(wb.Document));
     wb.Navigate(url);
     while (!ts.Task.IsCompleted) Application.DoEvents();
   });
   t.TrySetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
   t.Start();
   return ts.Task;
}

var t = Navigate(Uri("http://ru.stackoverflow.com"), 
            doc => {
               return doc.Body.InnerHtml;  // передается в t.Result
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть еще одна проблема вот в этих строчках.

```
while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) 
{ System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents(); }
```

В нормальном состоянии, при отсутствии событий программа засыпает и не расходует время процессора. Но ваш цикл так делать не умеет.

Цикл обработки событий надо "крутить" через `Application.Run`, обязательно передав ему любую форму - тогда с процессорным временем все будет в порядке.

Должно получиться примерно так:

```
static void RunGenerateScreenshotThread(string url)
{
    try
    {
        using (WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser())
        {
            // Set the size of the WebBrowser control
            wb.Width = width;
            wb.Height = height;

            wb.DocumentCompleted += (o, e) => Application.ExitThread();
            wb.Navigate(url);

            Application.Run(new Form { Visible = false });

            if (wb.DocumentTitle == "Navigation Canceled")
                Console.WriteLine("Natigated ERROR {0}", count);
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Natigated OK {0}", count);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Наличие формы предотвращает немедленной выход из цикла обработки сообщений.

Comment: _"надо "крутить" через Application.Run"_ -- почему? исходник [DoEvents()](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Application.cs,1017) и [Run()](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Application.cs,1478) одинаковые, только в Run создается ApplicationContext.

Comment: @Stack хм, спутал с реализацией из другого языка, видимо. Дело не в выбранном методе, а в наличии формы...

Comment: а код после `Application.Run` успевает выполниться после вызова `Application.ExitThread()`?

Comment: @Stack метод `Application.ExitThread` не останавливает поток - он всего лишь выходит из `Run`/`DoEvents`.